# How to identify a video card without a PC?

Tags: graphics-card

I have a video card that I need to identify without plugging it into a PC.

The photos are [here](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B9sdL93unR2TfmtkTjFrX0M0WlY2Ykd3RGpBZHdlNlFGOTNqR3dmNWhhczdfU3NiYy1pMnc&usp=sharing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be an HP NVIDIA GTX645 GAZELLE FH2G GDD according to the part number:

[image: Part Number]

- [Source 1](https://www.partsit.com/product/hp-724338-001)
- [Source 2](https://www.eafsupplychain.com/Product/HP-724338-001)
- [Same looking one for sale on AliExpress](http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Graphics-card-for-GTX645-2G-DDR5-GTX650-GT640-GTX740-724338-001-well-tested-working/32241519779.html)

Comment: That's just awesome, didn't knew it's possible to use part number) Thanks